# How to solve the "ERROR: No matching distribution found for typing-extensions"?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I download the whl files from http. And I run the command with

```
pip install "D:\CUDA\torch-1.12.0+cu113-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl"
```

but, it reports me error as following:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple/
Processing d:\cuda\torch-1.12.0+cu113-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/typing-extensions/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/typing-extensions/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/typing-extensions/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/typing-extensions/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/typing-extensions/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/typing-extensions/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/typing-extensions/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of torch to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement typing-extensions (from torch) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for typing-extensions
```

the preparation:
NVIDIA GPU: RTX A4000

```
nvcc -V
```

11.3

torchvision: 11.3 (torchvision-0.13.0+cu113-cp39-cp39-win_amd64)

torch: 11.3 (torch-1.12.0+cu113-cp39-cp39-win_amd64)

torchaudio: 11.3 (torchaudio-0.12.0+cu113-cp39-cp39-win_amd64)

Comment: "Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/typing-extensions/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/typing-extensions/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))" Someone or something is intercepting your HTTPS connections, and `pip` refuses to trust that self-signed certificate.

Comment: (The `torch*` wheels have other dependencies; if you downloaded the `torch` wheels by hand, you'd also need to get the dependency wheels. You can do that by `pip download` instead of `pip install`.)